# current way to use List in flutter for scrollable with expanded or flex

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

my screen is not scrollable , and has limit height ( only scrollable in the limit height )
I do want to make my page on there for scrollable, 
 here is my current page now :

[image: my page not scrollable]

if you see in the gif above, my page is not scrollable and only stuck in the one box and scrollable inside, I do love to scroll able them for all page normally, should I use ListView here ?? but how can I make the pic and text for responsive like above ? but I do make the hight of text too close also, can I know how u tiny up the text on the list also ??

here is my code for that Widget

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          data['title'],
          softWrap: true,
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.05),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Image.network('https://i.ibb.co/nrWqyMx/belgium.png'),
              )
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                    return Container(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.14,
                      child: ListTile(
                        leading: Icon(Icons.radio_button_checked, size: 17),
                        title: Text(data['ingredients'][index], style: TextStyle(height: 1.3),),
                      )
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: data['ingredients'].length,
                ),
              )
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

link : [flutter codepen](https://codepen.io/hoomacbuk/pen/MWajEjL?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=50d8d3334d372a2ddd375c9c15a736ae9b5cac47-1587396410-0-AWmmzpXNdvLkGl0HiEYk_BUFBhPNKxvpsgZgQJGWOJm-nTih7ZacR92rPWc25vANL027jLo-M27EjYPAc0NXarJEB5yVGR6IyvfOZTN49pN7T-qWO8ZS8te7JwtaynYp0xijUEqmGZFxkCui8vliA9bsp2DtmF5Smt6lwScvPyYzV5fL9S5z5aLBjlbRMmu_gEqmwJEJrYWLZH02FA2sRByUFVZ3hbwS5MHk9ZN-kp2Ip177oFv5wsPgO7IaMJ2iWF5GuUHr75iyVbjMeKSYZneAT-JBxV2nJ4yncxNM29zCvcVtqWR8igFMYnexHSMvfCi7PMuF-racvouHA3MjFp4-WnZKu1j1UvgUgB4NAFDm)

Answer (score 1):

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'MyAppBar',
          style:
          TextStyle(color: Colors.cyan[100], fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Image.network
                ('https://i.ibb.co/nrWqyMx/belgium.png'),
            ),
            ListView.builder(
              physics: ScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                return Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.14,
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(Icons.radio_button_checked, size: 17),
                      title: Text("data['ingredients'][index]", style: TextStyle(height: 1.3),),
                    )
                );
              },
              itemCount:25,
            )
          ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: this doesn't work: got error : `RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.`

Comment: You have to give hight of a container.

Comment: it takes more space when I scroll the page to up after the last text

Comment: Then adjust your height with List

Comment: but it will affect other devices which not has different hight is I did that??

Comment: That's why use `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height`

Comment: if I adjust to 1 ,MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1, the image and text tiny

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212096/discussion-between-sandeep-sharma-and-weq-iou).

Comment: Hey, I updated my answer. let me know if it working or not.

Comment: Hey, if this answer helps, accept it and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need put a ScrollView as a main container of your widget. Something like this:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text("Title"),
              ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: 3,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    height: 300,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      border: Border.all(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        style: BorderStyle.solid
                      )
                    ),
                  );
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work : got `RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.` after I add widget before Column

Comment: Are you using `shrinkWrap: true` like my example?

Comment: yesss I do that, I just add the SingeView on my code without change anything on my code, 
wrap the Singlview in Column and `shrinkWrap: true`